# read a csv file from the beginning after having reached the end (Java, OpenCSV)

Tags: java, opencsv

I want to use OpenCSV and Java to count how many lines a specific .csv file of mine has. Then, I want to parse every line of the file and do some stuff. I found some questions similar to mine and the most common answer to these questions was to use a loop to count the lines, as CSVReader class doesn't have a function that counts the lines of the file it's reading. My question is the following: After I count the lines, is there a way to read the file from the beginning after the first loop, without creating a new CSVReader object and String buffer? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I ended up using the readAll() member function of CSVReader class. It stores the whole file to a List of String arrays. Every row is a List node, with every entry of the row being a String in the String array. This way, you can also very easily get the number of rows like this:

```
List<String[]> records = csvReader.readAll();
int no_of_rows = records.size();
```

---

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CSV_Reader {
private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "some_path";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
        System.out.println("before new object");
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        String[] nextRecord;
        System.out.println("before while");

        int no_of_rows = 0;
        while ( (nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null ) {
            no_of_rows++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of lines is: " + no_of_rows );

        String[] string_vector = new String[no_of_rows];
        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            //I want to do some stuff here. It doesn't enter the loop as it is now...
        }
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but can't you close the first reader then do `Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));` again?

Comment: Also if the `CSV` is not extra large, why not just count the lines while storing the information in an object or data structure? Or just store the lines in a `List<someObject>` and the list size will be the line count.

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't enter the loop because the loop uses the CSVReader object created to parse the lines and not directly the reader object.

Comment: That's a good idea. I need to store all entries of a specific column to an array though (it explicitly has to be an array)  and I'm under the impression that arrays need to have predetermined size in Java (I'm new to Java, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: If you use ArrayList then you do not have to predefine the size. Then you can convert the ArrayList to Array if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using the readAll() member function of CSVReader class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if it is really something that you want to do by storing each line's data then here is what you can do.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
String[] nextRecord;
while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
  rows.add(Arrays.asList(nextRecord)); //rows is a list of list
  //do whatever you want to do
}
```